# Route Laravel Error

Tags: php

this is my routes

```
Route::get('/', 'frontcontroller@index');
Route::get('/index.html', 'frontcontroller@index');
Route::get('/checkout.html', 'frontcontroller@checkout');
Route::get('/furniture.html', 'frontcontroller@furniture');
Route::get('/login.html', 'frontcontroller@login');
Route::get('/products.html', 'frontcontroller@products');
Route::get('/register.html', 'frontcontroller@register');
Route::get('/single.html', 'frontcontroller@single');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin','middleware'=>'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('admin.index');
    })->name('admin.index');

 });
```

this is a side navigation:

```
{{-- Side Navigation --}}
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="sidebar content-box" style="display: block;">
        <ul class="nav">
            <!-- Main menu -->
            <li class="current"><a href="{{route('admin.index')}}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
                    Dashboard</a></li>
            <li class="submenu">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> Products
                    <span class="caret pull-right"></span>
                </a>
                <!-- Sub menu -->
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="{{route('admin.index')}}">Add Product</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div> <!-- ADMIN SIDE NAV-->
```

This is the route function

```
/**
     * Get the URL to a named route.
     *
     * @param  string  $name
     * @param  mixed   $parameters
     * @param  bool  $absolute
     * @return string
     *
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function route($name, $parameters = [], $absolute = true)
    {
        if (! is_null($route = $this->routes->getByName($name))) {
            return $this->toRoute($route, $parameters, $absolute);
        }

        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Route [{$name}] not defined.");
    }
```

Why I have this problem?

> Route [product.index] not defined. 
>   (View:C:\Users\Antonio\Desktop\uni\musicshop\resources\views\admin\layout\includes\sidenav.blade.php)
>   (View:C:\Users\Antonio\Desktop\uni\musicshop\resources\views\admin\layout\includes\sidenav.blade.php)
>   (View:C:\Users\Antonio\Desktop\uni\musicshop\resources\views\admin\layout\includes\sidenav.blade.php)

This is the code of the problem:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDvRi.png)

Comment: Upload the code, not a picture of the code, please.

Comment: I upload the code @castis

Comment: Show your routes, and sidenav.blade.php

Comment: ok i add @aynber

Comment: I don't see `product.index` anywhere, which is what it's complaining about. Is that anywhere in your sidenav?

Comment: yes yes  @aynber

Comment: Then you need to either name the product.index route as the answer below suggests, or use the actual route instead of using the name.

Answer (score 0):

you should set name route

Route::get('/products.html', 'frontcontroller@products')->name('product.index');